# How to open user system preferred editor for given file?

Tags: java, file, editor, system

I'm trying to figure out how to open the system preferred editor for a given file.

Say, we have a file manager, written in Java. User goes to folder and sees the list of files. And, for example, there is a file `Icon.jpg`. User double clicks on the filename and file opens in system's preferred editor (i.e. Gimp). The main issue is - how to do that?

We can do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("something file")`, but this way you should know which program is preferred in user environment. But how?

We also are able to do `Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File file)`, but this way we cannot track process and aren't able to know then this child process is closed. Other issue - function doesn't work on linux (at least on Ubuntu 8.10). There is also `Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file)`, but it forces to open file viewer, instead of system viewer for that file type.

I am searching for a solution all week, but didn't got any suitable and generic one. Do you know the other approaches to this question? For my project it would be enough if it would work on Windows+Linux+Mac.

Thank you for your answers and advices.

**Edit on 2009-02-08 23:04**

Other suggestion: can I force "application selection" window in Windows and in Linux, as in Mac with "open file"? For example, then you trying to open file, you are being asked to choose application from list of system preferred ones? (something like "Open with..." in Windows explorer). Do you know?

Comment: Other suggestion: can I force "application selection" window in Windows and in Linux, as in Mac? For example, then you trying to open file, then you are being asked to choose application from list of system predefines choices? (something like "Open with..." in windows explorer).

Do you know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that if you can't use `java.awt.Desktop` you have to distinguish between the OSes:
Windows:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL <file.ext>
```

Linux:

```
edit <file.ext>
```

Mac:

```
open <file.ext>
```

HTH. Obviously, that is not very portable...

Comment: These are console commands, which I supposed to write to Runtime.getRuntime().exec() function, right?

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Comment: This solution helped me to open other type of links: `ms-word:ofe|u|http://10.0.162.75:8081/alfresco/webdav/Myfiles/file_example.docx` ty

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) object.  In your case, you want to invoke [`edit()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit(java.io.File))

If you want to ensure that a given platform supports this call, then you can do something like the following (I have not tested this code):

```
public boolean editFile(final File file) {
  if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    return false;
  }

  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  if (!desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT)) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    desktop.edit(file);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Log an error
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I definitely know, that edit() doesn't works on Ubuntu. But this functionality is required for me. Do you know what I supposed to do if edit() is not supported?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't cross-platform, but on Mac OS X you can do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open filename");
```

The `open(1)` executable uses [LaunchServices](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/chapter_1_section_1.html) to pick the right program to execute, and then uses that to open the file named `filename`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. It is very useful for me, because for now I am able to test my code only on Ubuntu and Linux and have no idea how is it on Mac. :)

Answer (score 2):

For JavaFX applications, we can use HostServices. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094981/javafx-8-open-a-link-in-a-browser-without-reference-to-application/33100968#33100968) covers how to use HostServices. This should work on Ubuntu (tested)/Windows (not tested) and Mac (not tested).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class App extends Application {
}

File file = new File("/your/file/path");
HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

getHostServices() is a method of JavaFX Application class.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in windows

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "CMD /C START filename.ext " );
```

Comment: Nope. It won't ;p

Comment: Works on my Windows 10 Pro

Comment: It's worth to put filename in quotes to make statement safer (in case file contains spaces in name or path): `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"\" " + file.absolutePath + "\"");`