# Opening an Excel file using the default program

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

My program successfully creates and fills a Excel(.xls) file. Once created, I would like the new file to open in the system's default program (Excel in my case). How can I achieve this?

For an older program where I wanted to open a txt file in Notepad, I used the following:

```
if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        System.err.println("Desktop not supported");
        // use alternative (Runtime.exec)
        return;
    }

    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (!desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT)) {
        System.err.println("EDIT not supported");
        // use alternative (Runtime.exec)
        return;
    }

    try {
        desktop.edit(new File(this.outputFilePath));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I try to use this code for an Excel file it gives me the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to edit file:C:/foo.xls
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You may find similar answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/550336/2692703>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to use Desktop.open() instead of Desktop.edit() :

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(this.outputFilePath));
```

If Desktop.open() is not available then the Windows file association can be used :

```
Process p = 
  Runtime.getRuntime()
   .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + this.outputFilePath);
```

Comment: @suman, maybe  `xdg-open` to open the default application for a given file type, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably did the Runtime.exec incorrectly.  Give [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) a look to see if that's the case.

If you just want to open an Excel file with Java, I'd recommend using Andy Khan's JExcel API. Perhaps using that with a Swing JTable will be just the ticket.

Comment: Yes. Jexcel API prints colors more realistic than JRXlsExporter library

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and efficient way.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("inputFilePath"));
```