# Java download file from URL with unknown filename

Tags: java, file, excel, url, download

I have URL that gets called from my java app that returns the save/open dialog for an Excel file.

At the moment, it opens in a new tab but I want to return the dialog box in the same window. I do not know the file name as it is dynamic and changes based on the parameters passed in. 
I also do not want to save it somewhere as I want the user to have the choice of opening or saving.

Is there anyway of doing this in Java? I've only seen examples where the file name is known.

*EDIT* 
The URL is hitting a CGI Script

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)) object in your app from the url, store it in a temporary location then [ask Excel to open it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114318/opening-an-excel-file-using-the-default-program).

Comment: I would rather not store it in a temp location.

Comment: @pm13 You're going to have difficulty then, as you can *only* use Excel to open files if they're stored on the disk.

Comment: All I want is for the reponse from the URL, which is currently a Save As/Open dialog box, to be shown in the same window as the app, instead of opening in a new tab.

Comment: @pm13 That's not possible, that dialog belongs to the browser. If you want it to open in your app you'll need to re-implement it.