# Java open Excelfile and track windowstatus

Tags: java, excel

I want to open an Excel-file with Java.

I saw this [Opening an Excel file using the default program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114318/opening-an-excel-file-using-the-default-program) and this works perfectly.

(In short the solution would be:)

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(this.outputFilePath));
```

or

```
Process p = 
  Runtime.getRuntime()
   .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + this.outputFilePath);
```

But I also want to know when the Excel-file is closed again. Am I able to track, if the user closes the Excel-sheet? And would I use the process or the desktop-solution for this? What is the difference between this solutions?

I want to create an E-Mail after closing the Excel-file.

**Thanks to the comments**

I have a solution now.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",path);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: The latter will allow you to monitor the subprocess created, although I would use a ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.exec(...).

Comment: You can wait for the process to finish; the desktop option doesnt allow this, and sucks badly, too. You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004150/desktop-api-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform/18004334#18004334

Comment: With the Processbuilder, how would I open excel? I searched for it, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("excel",path);`

Comment: If you know how to set up the Runtime.exec(...) you can set up the ProcessBuilder. Please check the API.

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",path);`. This calls a "cmd.exe" that will open your Excel file with default program.