# Open specific file type with Python script?

Tags: python, default, file-association

How can I make a Python script to be a specific file type's (e.g., *.foo) default application? As in, when I double click the file in the Finder / Explorer I want the file to open in the Python script.

Is this possible to do in Win and/or OS X? The application is a PySide app if that matters.

Comment: Would invoking a Java stub work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program Otherwise I am quite sure that you are out of luck if you want a portable solution.

Comment: From that question, I was unable to find a way to open the file with any application.  That `.open` method seems to only open a file in the default application.  Even if you could, it wouldn't be a better solution than my answer as you would need a java application to open the python script.

Answer (score 3):

## Mac OS X

On **Mac OS X** you can use **Automator** to create an application that calls your python app and passes the input file path as a string argument. In the application workflow wizard, add action "Run Shell Script", select `Pass input:` as `as arguments`, and in the text box add:

```
python /path/to/my/app/myapp.py "$@"
```

The `"$@"` passes along whatever arguments were in the input (aka the selected file) as strings. As long as your script is set up to deal with the input (`sys.argv`) as a list of strings (the first one being the python app path), then it will work.

When you save that Automator workflow, it is treated by OS X like any other app, and you can set that app as the default for files of type "*.foo". To associate "*.foo" with that app, right click a .foo file, `Get Info`, `Open with: Other...`, choose the app you created in Automator, then click the `Change All...` button.

## Windows

A similar but hopefully less-involved approach might work in Windows. You could probably create a batch file (`.bat`) with the following:

```
python C:\path\to\my\app\myapp.py %*
```

The `%*` expands to all arguments.

As long as you can associate a file extension with that batch file, then you could do that, and that's your solution. However, I haven't tried this Windows solution, so take it with a grain of salt. The Mac solution, on the other hand, I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

By example, here's a universal solution I wrote for:
1) opening a Windows desktop link (*.URL) that's been copied to a Linux box.
Or 
2) opening a Linux .Desktop link that's been copied to a Windows box.

Here's the Python script that handles both cases:

```
# UseDesktopLink.py
import sys
import webbrowser
script, filename = sys.argv
file_object = open(filename,'r')
for line in file_object:
    if line[0:4]=="URL=":
        url=line[4:]
        webbrowser.open_new(url)
file_object.close()
```

On Windows, use Scott H's method (via a bat file) to handle the association.

On Linux, right-click a Windows URL file. Choose Properties, and Open With.  Click Add to add a new application. Then at the bottom of the "Add Application" window, click "Use a custom command". Then browse to the UseDesktopLink.py file and click Open. But before you click Add, in the textbox below "Use a custom command", put "python " before the filename (without the quotes). Then click Add and Close.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find *any* file of type `foo`
2. right-click -> `Get Info` or Click on the file icon,then click Get info or click on the file and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
3. In the `Open With` pane that shows up, select the path to the python binary
4. Once selected, You can click the `change All` button
5. It'll ask for confirmation, just say `continue`

Comment: Is there a way to choose a *.py file rather than a *.app (that has come from py2app or something?)?

Comment: for a `*.py` file you have to do the above steps with the `.py` instead of `foo` in step **1**

Comment: This is getting very confused. The OP has a python script, say myapp.py and wants to use it to automaticaly open files ending in .foo such as myfile.foo or whatever. Use the instructions in this answer, but in step 3 instead of associating your .foo file with a python binary, just associate it with your python application's .py file, e.g. myapp.py.

Comment: @SimonHibbs When I get to step 3 it's not possible to associate the arbitrary filetype with a .py file as OS X doesn't consider it an application. You can navigate to the script in the finder, but it's grayed out because it's not an application. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I found this old question while looking for an answer myself, and I thought I would share my solution.  I used a simple c program to direct the arguments to a python script, allowing the python script to stay a script instead of needing to compile it to make things work.  Here is my c program:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char cmd[0xFF];
    // For me, argv[1] is the location of the file that is being opened.  I'm not sure if this is different on other OSes
    snprintf(cmd,sizeof cmd,"python YOUR_PYTHON_SCRIPT_HERE.py -a %s", argv[1]);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

I then compiled the c program and set that as the default application for the file extension.
Then, in the python script YOUR_PYTHON_SCRIPT_HERE.py, I receive the argument like this:

```py
import sys
assert len(sys.argv) > 2 # Breaks if you call the script without the arguments
theFile = " ".join(sys.argv[2:]) # What the c program gives us 
print(theFile) # Print it out to prove that it works
```

theFile will contain the location of the file that is being opened
Get the contents of the file by using:

```
with open(theFile,"r") as f:
    fileContents = f.read()
```

Answer (score -4):

On Windows:

1. Right click the file (I used a `.docx` file for this example)
2. Select `Open with...`
3. From the applications list, select `python`
4. *Optional*: Select the `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`.

Note: this will *run* the contents of the `.docx` file in context of the python shell. It will  immediately close once it is finished evaluating the contents of the file. If you'd like to edit the file in a word processor, perhaps you should download [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.6.2.html), and select that application as the default.

Comment: The OP wants a particular file-type to open with _his own python script_, not with python itself.