# Register a python script as default for file type

Tags: python, default, file-extension, file-association

I am making an application with python which will need to be associated with a file type. I need a cross platform solution (can be different for different platforms) that includes setting the icon for the file type, having my application open when a file of that type is double-clicked and being able to reference that file when my application is opened.

**To clarify**
Lets say that I have an application called FooEdit, that edits `.foo` files. `.foo` files have the mime type of `text/plain`. Here is the process that happens when a user first gets FooEdit:

- A user obtains the executable for my application, whether it be on Linux, Windows, or OS X.
- A python script runs that:

  1. Sets FooEdit (the executable) as the default application for `.foo` file extensions.
  2. Sets the icon for `.foo` files to foofileicon.png (or foofileicon.ico if that works better).
- The same user double clicks a `.foo` file.
- FooEdit opens with the path to the file in it's `argv` array (I'm using PyQt4)

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693622/open-specific-file-type-with-python-script), but it only refers to Mac OS X and the user must do it manually, I want the solution to work on all three of the major platforms (Linux, Windows, OS X) and I want it to be done automatically by the python script.
I have also heard about inserting values into the windows registry for such a purpose and I am fine with doing that for the windows version of my program. However that still leaves me clueless as to how to do the same on Mac and Linux.
I would like a single solution that works on all platforms, though I accept that it might well not be possible.

Comment: Registering applications to file types is very system specific, most probably you'd need to write handler for every OS. Some information about creating file type & registering it on Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31836/1483826, and on Mac OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2976711/1483826.

Comment: Also information for Windows (using the assoc command) http://superuser.com/questions/406985/programatically-associate-file-extensions-with-application-on-windows

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I couldn't find those myself.