# Change Windows File Handler to a Python script to open a file

Tags: python, parsing

I'm interested in associating a certain file extension let's call it '.abc' with a Python script that I want to develop.

When the .abc file is double clicked, I would like it to be parsed by my Python script.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you
Chris

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041571/associate-file-extension-to-python-script-so-that-i-can-open-the-file-by-double

Comment: Thank you - How do I associate .docx with a Python file handler?