How to know file address when I open it with a .exe file converted from .py file?
I have a .exe file(converted from .py file) and .teui file.
When I click .teui file and choose open with .exe file, then I want .exe file return address of .teui file.
(select and right-click file -> open-with -> ToolsEngine_UI.exe)
Ex: When you click on the .py/.cpp/.java file, then vscode will open up and know which file you just clicked and open it for you to read.
How can I do that in Python???

Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041571/associate-file-extension-to-python-script-so-that-i-can-open-the-file-by-double ?

I suspect the .teui name is in sys.argv but the .exe conversion might affect that.

As pointed out by @MSalters, What is the preferred Bash shebang ("#!")? answers the question by adding a shebang at the very first line of the file (e.g., #!/usr/bin/python), which points the file to the executable it should run the file with. However, that is not good practice. You should run your commands from the command line (python3 myscript.py), as others might not have their Python script in the location you specified in the shebang. For example, my Python3 installation runs under /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/python3.
Also, Java and C++ usually require build steps before producing an executable file. This requires build systems and scripts adjusting the parameters of the build. Therefore, you might progress well if you get used to running commands directly from the command line.

I think either you or StackOverflow has a link confused. Shebangs don't work in Windows.

You are right, Windows wouldn't have that :)
