# calling jsp page from java class opens it in dreamviewer so how can i open jsp page in eclipse itself?

Tags: java, jsp, dreamweaver

I have a normal java class which calls JSPpage as soon as control goes to JSP page, the page itself opens in Dreamweaver but I want it to be opened in eclipse itself with its default browser. how can I accomplish this?

This is my code:

```
String htmlFilePath = "WebContent/raja.
File htmlFile = new File(htmlFilePath);
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);
```

Comment: JSP runs under web container like tomcat. Exactly what are you asking is bit vague.

Comment: i have java class after running this java application, i want to display jsp page. So the above code was written after all the functionality is done.

Comment: actually i think you have added a server in your dreamviwer and while creating your project you have added the server from dreamviewer , i would suggest , go to your jsp page , run configuration , remove old server and add new one , or do thi with your complete project

Comment: my project does not need any server. let me tel you this. I have java application once the work is done, it simply calls jsp page where it display some image. so it is nothing to do with server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to say you have a simple Java standalone desktop application and not a web-application?

If yes than I would say, JSP's require a servlet-container to be executed.

But by the look of your code it seems that you are not trying to execute but just fetch the JSP which will be fetched just as other files are fetched (like files with extension `.html`, `.txt`, `.jsp`, `.php`, `.doc`).

> the page itself opens in Dreamweaver but I want it to be opened in eclipse itself with its default browser

I hope you have read the API for the [Desktop#open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) method, it clearly says:

> Launches the associated application to open the file.
>
> If the specified file is a directory, the file manager of the current platform is launched to open it.

So this means if the file you are fetching has `.doc` extension it would open the file in MS-WORD and if the extension is `.txt` it might open `notepad` or any text-editor which is configured as the default associated application.

So it seems the files with `.jsp` extensions have dreamweaver as the default associated application. So this seems to be a configuration of the underlying platform rather than a code issue.

Currently I don't know if it is possible to change the default associated application for a particular file extension through code dynamically.

This question may also help: [How to open a file with the default associated program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program)

Comment: thank you prashant for your reply but i do not want to use any servlet. I am just using java class and calling jsp from that java class...is it possible?

Comment: @RajeshAcharya JSP (Java SERVER Pages) are a server side technology. You'll need to run some sort of server to have them processed, I guess... Just fetching them gets you the raw pages as you coded them, not the processed result.

Comment: @RajeshAcharya You mean you want to open the browser and show the processed JSP i.e. all the scriptlets and jstl tags executed and converted to HTML instead of the raw JSP? Well this is not possible may be if you can tell us your detailed requirement as to what you want to do then may be we can help provide an alternative.

Comment: please help me out prakash bhai. all i want to do is after processing the simple java class i need to redirect the page to jsp. so jsp should open whatever the condition it is.

Comment: @RajeshAcharya I have already told you that simply running a java application without a servlet container is not going to execute your JSP and moreover JSPs after being executed give nothing but HTML code which could be displayed in a web-browser. So please state your requirements or usecases in some detail so that we can think of an alternative rather than guessing what exactly you are doing and what you want to do. Thanks

Comment: ha...you  were right. I had to use servlet to get the result and using redirect i was able to get the jsp page..thank you for your patience prakash,