# How to open a file using a JButton

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a file, we can call it 'example.txt' and I've already called the file in my program. I want to add functionality to open the file when a JButton, `myButton` is clicked. This is my code so far:

```
myButton.setText("Button");
 File example_file = new File("~/path/to/example.txt");
 myButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
     myButtonActionPerformed(evt);
   }
 });

private void myButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
   //open the file
}
```

I'm sure there is a very simple way to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: you have to read the contens of the txt file, save it to a String and then output the String

Comment: @alexandre1985 what if the file is not a txt file? Is there no way to actually open a file using JButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file);
```

This might help you:

[Related Question and Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program)

Comment: *"Related Question and Answer."* Then you should have voted to close the question as a duplicate and commented the fact

Answer (score 1):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new java.io.File("path to file"));
```

Just a suggestion:
Learn C\C++ for these kind of jobs. I did.