# How to open a file in a default text editor with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have a simple Gui that lets a FileChooser select a text file. When I click on a button, I want the file to open in a default text editor, how do I do that with JavaFX, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How to open a file with the default associated program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program)

Just call

> Desktop.getDesktop.open(yourFile);