# Minor Issue when saving vs retrieving file extension in java

Tags: java, regex

This is not one of those questions for which I dont know a answer but I am trying to find a better more effective way so here I go.

when saving file name in java I am saving it like this

```
private static final String REPORT_FILE_PREFIX = "ask_ques"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final String TXT_EXTENSION = ".txt"; //$NON-NLS-1$
StringBuilder fileName= new StringBuilder();
fileName.append(tempFilePath.toString()).append(REPORT_FILE_PREFIX)
                .append(uniqueId.toString()).append(TXT_EXTENSION);
```

This is going to save the file something like  `ask_ques_1234.txt` all is well and good. Now when opening the file I need to open in based on its extension like notepad for txt, excel so on and so forth.Like I do below

```
 if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName.getName()) == CSV_EXTENSION) {
            // Open the .csv file based on the local file type
            // association

        } else if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName.getName()) == TXT_EXTENSION) {
           // open the .txt file based on file type assocaition
}
```

the problem here is that `FilenameUtils.getExtension(reportFile.getName())` returns a value of txt but TXT_EXTENSION has `.txt` as its value.

Do not want to create static variable for the `.`. Wanted to see if there is simeple regex or something similar you guys know off to ignore the `.` when comparing.

Comment: You probably don't want `==` for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: thanks for the idea @PM77-1 did a slight tweak and it works wonders.
if (CSV_EXTENSION.equalsIgnoreCase("." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(reportFile.getName())))

Comment: I suggest having `TXT_EXTENSION = "txt"`and then `...append('.').append(TXT_EXTENSION)`

Comment: Are you actually trying to open a file based on local file type association, as the comment says? As in, launch the appropriate app for it? Because in that case you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: care to expand on it I am curious

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program  If you're reimplementing that in your own app, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `fileName.getName()) == CSV_EXTENSION` use `fileName.getName()).equals(CSV_EXTENSION)`.

In Java `==` stands for reference comparision and `String#equals` compares `char` by `char`.

To compare `csv` with `.csv` you can try the following:

```
CSV_EXTENSION.substring(1).equals(fileName.getName()))
```

Comment: `fileName.getName()` returns extension without the dot. So maybe concat a dot with `fileName.getName()` and then compare it with `CSL_EXTENSIION`

Comment: yep thanks for that also I replaced equals with equalsIgnoreCase for good measure and also flipped the order to prevent null pointer exception

Comment: also like what you did with substring nice idea