# getHostServices().showDocument() in a FXML File

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Is there any easy way to put into the toHomepage() method the getHostServices().showDocument() command somehow, instead of doing lines and lines of code, so the code should look clean and simple?

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

   @FXML
   private Button facebookButton;

   @FXML
   void toHomepage(ActionEvent event) {

   }


}
```

If I press the button, it should directly link me to the Facebook URL

Comment: You need to pass the `getHostServices()` to the `Controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `HostServices` to the `Controller`.

> Key Code: Set the `HostServices` in the `Controller`.

```
HostServices hostServices ;

public void setGetHostController(HostServices hostServices)
{
    this.hostServices = hostServices;
}
```

> Key Code: Passing `HostServices` to the `Controller`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
FXMLDocumentController fXMLDocumentController = loader.getController();
fXMLDocumentController.setGetHostController(getHostServices());
```

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication7 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        FXMLDocumentController fXMLDocumentController = loader.getController();
        fXMLDocumentController.setGetHostController(getHostServices());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author sedri
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    HostServices hostServices;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        hostServices.showDocument("www.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    public void setGetHostController(HostServices hostServices)
    {
        this.hostServices = hostServices;
    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication7.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer!
So like I see there is no code for this, that is short like a line?