# javafx transfer text from label across screens

Tags: java, javafx

I've searched and I'm sure that others have this problem as well. Many of the posts are unanswered or down voted and no solution is given, even to my own post. I wanted to know how I could transfer label data among classes. For example, say I have the following:

First Class:

```
Label lab;
public void setText() {
   lab.setText("hello");
}
public String getText() {
   return lab.getText();
}
public void switchScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
//code to switch scenes when button pressed
setText(); //this is also called when button pressed

}
```

Middle Class:

```
public void switchScenes(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FirstScreenController p = new FirstScreenController();
    n.displayAmt(p.getText()); //get text from first scene's label
}
```

Target Class:

```
Label otherLab;
public void displayAmt(String amt) {
    otherLab.setText(amt); //set text from first scene's label to this label
}
```

Suppose the middle class method is set to a button. Upon clicking the button, everything seems to work fine as the program switches scenes. However, otherLab in the Target class is empty. The text from the label in the first class was unsuccessfully transferred to the label in the target class.

How would one go about fixing this? I know that java is pass-by-value so the first label wont carry changes made by the function. What can be done to overcome this?

Comment: It's not recommended that you do something like that. Simply, pass the `Label's` data to the new controller and create a new `Label` using the data.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me a NullPointerException. I just cant overcome pass-by-value since java doesn't have pass-by-reference.

Comment: If you want to know how to pass information between controllers go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file/50775157#50775157) .

Comment: That example passes the `HostService`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I want to get data from a label (set by user input) and set it to a label in another class.

Comment: Do not take the advice of either answer. They will lead you to new problems. You should do what I did in the link I provide. Alter it to fit your situation.

Comment: After looking at your linked question, I see you did use the approach I suggested. You did not do a good job at describing your problem and adding supplement code to demostrate it. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will be able to get better help then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to add more to improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

With the following line every time you switch the scene you're creating a new controller object with an empty label so the getText in the middle class returns an empty line.

```
FirstScreenController p = new FirstScreenController();
```

Why you need a label text? This is not a user input or something like that, a label is just a label, fixed text, if you need a label in the second screen create a new one.If your question is: how to share parameters between scenes it depends from case to case, you can read from a file or something like that, but if you're trying to do that your question is how to share information between classes, that it's not about javafx.

Comment: This was my main question but it was down voted and ignored. I actually did have user input that I wanted to transfer across labels. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777024/storing-data-for-atm-app?noredirect=1#comment88562309_50777024

Comment: Yeah it makes sense that changes aren't carried when creating a new instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer suggested, you are creating a new object and so the getText method will return null;
You can use the writer and reader classes of the java.io package. 
The get text can include code to store the text in file with a writer and the target class can read from that file via a reader.
It should not be an expensive procedure.

A good link for io:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/index.htm
If it was jsp you can get parameters but these values are run time to you need to persist them.
Serialization is also an option.

Comment: I cant seem to save the label text anywhere. It just saves it as null. When I set a value to the label with user input, it displays it on the screen. When i try to get that text, it doesn't work. This is all in the first class.