# JavaFx SceneBuilder - Cannot update Label text - NullPointerException

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How I load it:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(new File("src/dreambot/guis/XPTracker.fxml").toURI().toURL());
        Controller l = (Controller) loader.getControllerFactory();
        primaryStage.setTitle("XP Tracker");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        l.setAtkXph(23233);
    }

    public void build(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Label atkXph;

    public void setAtkXph(int num) {
        atkXph.setText(num + "/h");
    }
}
```

Main(String[] args) method

```
public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().build(args);
    }
}
```

The label in my fxml:

```
<Label id="atkXph" fx:id="atkXph" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="71.0" text="0/h" />
```

My error:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dreambot.main.App.start(App.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: hmm ... might be unrelated, but casting ControllerFactory to Controller looks fishy ..

Comment: Look at the key code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file/50775157#50775157.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getHostServices().showDocument() in a FXML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Controller and controller factory are 2 different things:

The controller is the object that contains methods used with `#methodName` attribute values and fields that the loader injects objects to based on `fx:id`s.

The controller factory is used to create a controller, if you assign one to it.

```
controllerFactory.call(Class.forName(<fx:controller attribute value>))
```

is used by `FXMLLoader` to create an instance of the controller class, if you assign a `Callback` before loading the fxml.

Furthermore you use one of the `static` `load` method. This way a second `FXMLLoader` instance you cannot access is created and used to load the fxml. You need to specify the `URL` as location before loading the fxml.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("src/dreambot/guis/XPTracker.fxml").toURI().toURL()); // maybe replace with resource access (getClass().getResource("/dreambot/guis/XPTracker.fxml"))?
Parent root = loader.load();
Controller l = loader.getController();
```

Also you cannot create the instance of the `Application` class yourself and use the standard way of launching. `Application.launch` always creates a new instance of the application class. In this ase making the `build` method `static` would serve the same purpose, but you can also specify the application class using the overloaded version of `launch`:

```
Application.launch(App.class, args);
```