# JavaFX returning null to a User that is listed

Tags: java, javafx, crud

I'm making a "twitter" desktop application with JavaFX, where I need to make certain operations with users, but I have a problem searching the users I've created. When I'm using a standard main class, I get the user I wanted without problems, but when I'm using JavaFX it returns null for the user, even it shows at the console that the user is there (at the repository).

Main class (uses JavaFX):

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private static Scene mainScene;
    public static MyTwitterService service;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui/View.fxml"));
            ScrollPane scrollPane = loader.load();

            scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
            scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

            mainScene = new Scene(scrollPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("MyTwitter");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static Scene getMainScene() {
        return mainScene;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UJCException, PEException {
        service = new MyTwitterService();
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

My "Twitter service":

```
public class MyTwitterService {
    private RepositorioUsuario repositorio;
    private MyTwitter tt;
    
    public MyTwitterService() {
        this.repositorio = new RepositorioUsuario();
        this.tt = new MyTwitter(repositorio);
    }
    
    public Perfil search(String user) {
        return repositorio.buscar(user);
    }
}
```

The User Respository:

```
public class RepositorioUsuario implements IRepositorioUsuario{
    private ArrayList<Perfil> usuarios;
    
    public RepositorioUsuario() {
        usuarios = new ArrayList<Perfil>();
    }
    @Override
    public Perfil buscar(String usuario) {
        for(Perfil p : usuarios) {
            if(p.getUsuario() == usuario) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally, the View Controller:

```
import application.Main;
import entities.PessoaFisica;
import exceptions.PEException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CriarPerfilController {
    @FXML
    private TextField txtUserName;

    @FXML
    private Button btCriarPerfil;

    @FXML
    public void onBtCriarPerfilAction() throws PEException {
        System.out.println(Main.service.search(txtUserName.getText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Just a guess. Try doing `public static MyTwitterService service;` in the controller. The other option is to pass `service` to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import application.Main;
import entities.PessoaFisica;
import exceptions.PEException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CriarPerfilController {
    public MyTwitterService service;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUserName;

    @FXML
    private Button btCriarPerfil;

    @FXML
    public void onBtCriarPerfilAction() throws PEException {
        System.out.println(service.search(txtUserName.getText()));
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        service = new MyTwitterService();
    }
}
```

The other option is to pass `service` to the controller when loading the `FXML`. You can use the technique that is used to pass `HostServices` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file/50775157#50775157) example.