# Java: How to launch system's registered application for a URL

Tags: java, url, desktop

In Java 5, is there a default way to pass a URL to the system and have it launch the application associated with it?
For example http:// links would usually open IE or Firefox, but things like itms:// should open iTunes.

If possible I would rather not use Runtime.exec() to start some external process directly, because this would be platform specific. If there is no other way, what would I call for Windows/OS X and Linux to cover the most popular ones?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526037/java-how-to-open-user-system-preffered-editor-for-given-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ivan that Java Desktop API would work, but it's 6 only.

I know how to do it on Windows (it involves executing rundll32.dll), but I did some quick Googling and [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/LaunchBrowserinMacLinuxUnix.htm) seems like your best shot.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Java Desktop API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)

```
 Desktop desktop =  Desktop.getDesktop();
 if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
     desktop.browse(uri);
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that was added until Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 5, try [JDIC.](https://jdic.dev.java.net/) It has cross-platform support for [opening the OS's registered application for a file.](https://jdic.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/javadoc/jdic/org/jdesktop/jdic/desktop/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) If I remember correctly, this formed the basis for the similar API added in Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

[BrowserLauncher](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/) does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Windows it's "start [URI]", OSX it's "open [URI]", Linux has no equivalent as it all depends upon their window manager.

As for whether itms:// opens iTunes, that all depends on their configuration.

Ivan's answer appears much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) but I think it was introduced in 1.6 and wasn't available in 5...:-(