# Let user choose the application to open the file

Tags: java, windows, swing, file-io, jdesktop

I need my java code to open a file based upon the default application. Thanks to 
[How to open user system preferred editor for given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526037/how-to-open-user-system-preffered-editor-for-given-file) which suggests a quality method to do it by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL "+file);
```

But the issue is that, once I select the application to open it up, it doesn't open the file. I do not know the reason for it.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

This opens in default application. I want the user to choose the application to open it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use :

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)

EDIT:

Here is the code to make your command work:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestExec {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("d:/Clipboard1.png");
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("RUNDLL32.EXE", "SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL", file.getAbsolutePath());
        builder.redirectErrorStream();
        builder.redirectOutput();
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }

}
```

Comment: This opens in default application. I want the user to choose the applciation to open it up

Comment: @Jatin: your title says: "Open file from default application". This is what it does.