# Open mp3 file using specific applications java

Tags: java, file, media-player, desktop

I want to know if there is a way of opening mp3 files using either Windows Media Player and VLC Media Player. 
I have the path of the file saved as a String and was wondering if I can use this to open the file on either of the applications mentioned above.
I understand one method of doing this is by using the Desktop class but this opens the file using the default application, which is Windows Media Player in my case. How would I open the file in VLC media player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<your vlc path> <your file>");
```

I.E.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\VLC\\vlc.exe\" abc.mp3");
```

Tried and it works

Comment: This method works only when the file path does not contain spaces. How can amend this to work with any file name?
`Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\""+path);`The path variable contains spaces.

Comment: @user1909680 Just add double quotes around your path `Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" \""+path+"\"");`, if you don't know what `\"` is, it is an escape character for `"`, it tells the compiler that this double quote is not for closing the string, but it is for adding a `"` to it

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [`Desktop.open` apidoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) and
[Desktop tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) it looks like the open method can *only* open the file in their default associated program.

So, you have (maybe) two options here:

- [access the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) and change the default association (not a nice one)
- might try giving a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) and opening it via browser, which *might* result in opening the file in desired program. However, it looks like the `file` scheme is the only acceptable solution, and that will most probably open in the *default* program. There is a `mms` scheme but it is used for video-streaming, and again, it will most probably open in the default program.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526080/679982) to the `Runtime.exec` solution for windows, linux and osx variant.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the path to the `VLC` and/or `WMP`. Then you can use [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class for this.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:/vlc/vlc.exe " + mp3FileName);
```